# Upload Directory question

Tags: redirect, uploads

Happy New year!

So I am having a big of a problem, currently one of our php files that we bought points to the default uploads directory for wordpress and we would like to change this to our own uploads directory.

We are still using the default uploads directory for wordpress but we want to change the directory where this custom php file uploads to.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir['basedir'].'/downloads/encrypted/'.$item.'/*'));
```

It currently looks like this "www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/encrypted/"

We want it to point to "www.example.com/downloads/encrypted/"

Have looked into the arrays for `wp_upload_dir();` but cannot seem to go a folder back. Any tips or help?

Thanks

Comment: Hook into said custom file or as last resort just edit it?

Comment: Hi Rarst, I would like to edit the file but edit it to what? I tired to edit it to `$url = site_url ();` and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
function wp128084_upload_dir( $pathdata ) {
     // change path here
     return $pathdata;
}

add_filter('upload_dir', 'wp128084_upload_dir');
```

add this where you want to change upload directory then again remove filter
to change to default wordpress directory

```
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wp128084_upload_dir');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `UPLOADS` constant.

Add the following line in your `wp-config.php` file

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'downloads/encrypted' );
```